# How to receive file from multiple clients?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I created a program which will send a file to the server or to clients

my problem is I have 2 clients and they both need to send a file to the server
what happens is that the server is able to receive the file only from 1 client(the one who sends the file first)

how can I resolve this problem?

here's my code:

**SERVER**

```
private void sendFile(File file)throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = null;
    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    String receiver=txtReceiver.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int port=0;
    if(receiver=="Client1")
    {
        host="127.0.0.2";
        port=4441;
    }
    else if(receiver=="Client2")
    {
        port=4442;
        host="127.0.0.3";
    }
    else if(receiver=="Server")
    {
        port=4440;
        host="127.0.0.1";
    }

    socket = new Socket(host, port);

    //File file = new File("Client.txt");
    // Get the size of the file
    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("File is too large.");
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    int count;

    while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
    socket.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4440);
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    int bufferSize = 0;

    try
    {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
    }

    try 
    {
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
    }

    try 
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jake_PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\OJT2\\ServerReceivables\\file.txt");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found. ");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

    int count;

    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
    {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    is.close();
    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
```

**CLIENT**

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4441);
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    int bufferSize = 0;

    try
    {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
    }

    try 
    {
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
    }
    //C:\Users\Jake_PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OJT2
    try 
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jake_PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\OJT2\\Client1Receivables\\file.txt");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found. ");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

    int count;

    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
    {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    is.close();
    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}

private void sendFile(File file)throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = null;
    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    String receiver=txtReceiver.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int port=0;
    if(receiver=="Client1")
    {
        port=4441;
    }
    else if(receiver=="Client2")
    {
        port=4442;
    }
    else if(receiver=="Server")
    {
        port=4440;
    }

    socket = new Socket(host, port);

    //File file = new File("Client.txt");
    // Get the size of the file
    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("File is too large.");
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    int count;

    while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: use same port for server and client and run two clients in different machines.

Comment: same port for server and client? if that's the case how will I know who will be the one to receive ?

Comment: Why you have [tag:swing] tag in your question? I cannot see anything related to swing.

Comment: oops sorry I'll take it off ((: i just thought because i'm using it on swings :D

Comment: Do you have same program for server and client ?

Comment: yes (: I just changed the ports of server client1 & client2... 

I tried changing all their ports to 4444 but only 1 can connect :D since I don't have any spare laptops with me :D

Comment: @AStranger I edited the post and put all the code besides CLIENT2 since CLIENT1 and CLIENT2 are almost the same :D

Comment: did you try running different instance of the same program ?.

Comment: I didn't get that sorry my english is poor can you explain that briefly? how running different instance of the same program? you mean? running the server code two times?

Comment: yep but one as server and next as client. differenciation is done by command line argument. Its just a try :)

Comment: wait do I still have to change they're port# ? or server can stay at port 4440 client1 in 4441 and client2 in 4442

if I don't have to change them then they run without catching exceptions... while if I changed they're ports to 4444, it catches an IOexception

Comment: You don't have to change any port numbers.

Comment: I figured out how to receive from both client1 and client2 ... now my problem is if I'll do it in multiple computers how do I get the IP of the one who'll be using Client 1 and Client 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a new thread to handle each accepted socket. Examples abound. See for example the Custom Networking trail in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: is it possible for me to try this in one computer only?

Comment: Yes indeed, it certainly is.

Comment: I updated the post and post all of the codes I made for both server and client... 
I wanted to do a 2 way communication between server and clients... what do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: haha thanks to this I had an idea to try a do while loop on the receiving part :D and it worked! thx a lot :D